# How do i retrieve all documents from a collection and its relevant information? (React Native Firebase)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

[Firebase hierarchy image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqCzr.png)

I have a collection named "Tickets"
Inside the collection contains many ticketID and its relevant information.

How can I display all the TicketID and the information in each sub ticket??

I am using React Native and Firebase.

[Firebase design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQtmv.png)

I've tried doing this:

```
firebase.firestore()
        .collection("tickets")
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            const documents = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
            // do something with documents
            console.log(documents);
        })
```

And the result is:

```
Array []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are querying for the tickets, and you should be getting their data e.g. the fields for each ticket. But you want data for the ticket's subcollection, 'userTickets'.

You can get data for all 'userTickets' subcollections by using a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query):

```
firebase.firestore()
  .collectionGroup('userTickets')
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    const documents = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
    // do something with documents
    console.log(documents);
  });
```

Comment: Ohh myy, you are amazingg, i did not know about collectionGroup. It worked, thank you so much!!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {}

getTickets() {
    return this.db.collection('tickets').get().then(querySnapshot => {
         const tickets = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
         // you can call getUserTicketsById here to add data from userTicket collection to ticket
         // ticktes.forEach(ticket => {const ticketData = this.getUserTicketsById(ticket.id); ticket.userTicket = ticketData})
         console.log(tickets);
         return tickets;
    })
}

getUserTicketsById(userId) {
    return this.db.collection(`tickets/${userId}/userTickets`).get().then(querySnapshot => {
         const userTickets = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
         // do something with documents
         
         console.log(userTickets);
         return userTickets;
    })
}
```